# IAR Embedded Workbench 5.3 Kickstart Migration error

Tags: embedded, workbench, iar

I was following a tutorial on how to migrate a freeRTOS project into IAR embedded workbench. In [step 2 & 3, under usage guidelines](https://github.com/IARSystems/project-migration-tools#installation), it specifies that all I have to do is simply add the project.

I did use "add new source folder" but instead of it copying the directory tree (as in step 4) it returns a single ".ipcf" file (as seen in the attached photo) and I'm not sure what to do with it.

My question is that[image] did the EWPtool fail or can I use this .ipcf file in some other way?

Comment: Can you please specify the target MCU architecture of your IAR Embedded Workbench (e.g. ARM, AVR, etc.)?

Comment: This is for AMTEL AT91SAM9G20

Comment: The recently updated FAQ section of the [Github project page](https://github.com/IARSystems/project-migration-tools) mentions that the option `Tools → Options → Project → Enable Project Connections` needs to be enabled.

Can you check whether it is enabled in your workbench? If the option is not present, your workbench version is not compatible (i.e. too old).

Comment: ARM version of IAR Workbench 5.5 doesn't support project connections, so it is very likely that yours doesn't either.